# external image in RDLC report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to use an external image on a report in my application. It's a windows application form.

The property `EnableExternalImages` of `localreport` is True
The source of image is External
As value i'm trying this. `file:///C:\image.png`

I can see the image on the report from visual studio designer, but when I run my application I can't see the image on the report but only a red X.

What can I do?

UPDATE 
I tried the same on a different computer and it works good. So the problem is with my laptop. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and spent two solid days finding a solution. In my case, I was using Dataset objects to populate the data on the report. So, before I refreshed the report, I saved the image into an array of bytes, then on the report set the image source to "Database", selected the corresponding Dataset object, then chose the column that contained the array of bytes. The images appeared in the report when viewing it in both a ReportViewer object and as a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a permission problem? try from your laptop, put the image in a different location where permission is not needed like in documents folder and see if issue still the same.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I thought the same, actually I already tried to change directory, but issue is still the same.

Comment: Have you found a solution?